# Resize image and caption with flexbox

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

Let's say I have a `div` that's exactly the dimensions of the browser window, and inside that `div` I want to put an image and a separate `div` that contains a caption (just text). I want to arrange and scale these elements to meet certain requirements:

- The container div should have some padding, so that nothing touches the edges of the viewport.
- The image and caption together should take up as much space as possible within the larger div, regardless of the proportions of the image, and regardless of the length of the caption.
- The caption should be only as wide as the image, so that it appears to fit directly underneath. (Extremely narrow images present a problem here, so perhaps the caption has a min-width.)

That's it! It sounds like the sort of problem flexbox was made to solve, and yet I haven't had  any luck.

Answer (score -1):

Use JavaScript to proportion the elements to the screen height/width:

```
<div id='container' style='padding:10px;'>
<img id='image' src=''>
</img>
<div id='caption' style='font-size:45px;'>
Caption Text
</div>
</div>
<script>
var imgwidth = (980/1000) * screen.width
var img = document.getElementById('image').style
img.position = "Absolute"
img.width = imgwidth
img.height = (700/1000) * screen.height
var cpn = document.getElementById('caption').style
cpn.position = "relative"
cpn.top = (700/1000) * screen.height + 30
cpn.width = imgwidth
</script>
```

Comment: To improve your answer, you may want to add a bit of commentary as to *how* your answer works and solves the OP's problem.

Comment: Javascript is definitely one way to go. Curious about flexbox because (browser support aside) it would probably be a more elegant solution.